# Is there a .NET namespace where I can find the WIN32 API message-related #defines, like WM_COMMAND, etc

Tags: .net, winapi, wndproc

I'm overriding WndProc, so I want to write code like

```
if (m.Msg == WM_COMMAND)
    my special stuff
else
    base.WndProc(ref m)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK .NET does not ship with these constants. This [site](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WM.html) has all the values so is a matter of copy paste.

```
private const UInt32 WM_ACTIVATE           = 0x0006;
private const UInt32 WM_ACTIVATEAPP        = 0x001C;
private const UInt32 WM_AFXFIRST           = 0x0360;
private const UInt32 WM_AFXLAST        = 0x037F;
private const UInt32 WM_APP            = 0x8000;
private const UInt32 WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME    = 0x030C;
private const UInt32 WM_CANCELJOURNAL      = 0x004B;
private const UInt32 WM_CANCELMODE         = 0x001F;
private const UInt32 WM_CAPTURECHANGED     = 0x0215;
private const UInt32 WM_CHANGECBCHAIN      = 0x030D;
private const UInt32 WM_CHANGEUISTATE      = 0x0127;
private const UInt32 WM_CHAR           = 0x0102;
private const UInt32 WM_CHARTOITEM         = 0x002F;
private const UInt32 WM_CHILDACTIVATE      = 0x0022;
private const UInt32 WM_CLEAR          = 0x0303;
private const UInt32 WM_CLOSE          = 0x0010;
private const UInt32 WM_COMMAND        = 0x0111;
private const UInt32 WM_COMPACTING         = 0x0041;
private const UInt32 WM_COMPAREITEM        = 0x0039;
private const UInt32 WM_CONTEXTMENU        = 0x007B;
private const UInt32 WM_COPY           = 0x0301;
private const UInt32 WM_COPYDATA           = 0x004A;
private const UInt32 WM_CREATE         = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORBTN        = 0x0135;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORDLG        = 0x0136;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLOREDIT       = 0x0133;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX    = 0x0134;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX     = 0x0132;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR      = 0x0137;
private const UInt32 WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC     = 0x0138;
private const UInt32 WM_CUT            = 0x0300;
private const UInt32 WM_DEADCHAR           = 0x0103;
private const UInt32 WM_DELETEITEM         = 0x002D;
private const UInt32 WM_DESTROY        = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD       = 0x0307;
private const UInt32 WM_DEVICECHANGE       = 0x0219;
private const UInt32 WM_DEVMODECHANGE      = 0x001B;
private const UInt32 WM_DISPLAYCHANGE      = 0x007E;
private const UInt32 WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD      = 0x0308;
private const UInt32 WM_DRAWITEM           = 0x002B;
private const UInt32 WM_DROPFILES          = 0x0233;
private const UInt32 WM_ENABLE         = 0x000A;
private const UInt32 WM_ENDSESSION         = 0x0016;
private const UInt32 WM_ENTERIDLE          = 0x0121;
private const UInt32 WM_ENTERMENULOOP      = 0x0211;
private const UInt32 WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE      = 0x0231;
private const UInt32 WM_ERASEBKGND         = 0x0014;
private const UInt32 WM_EXITMENULOOP       = 0x0212;
private const UInt32 WM_EXITSIZEMOVE       = 0x0232;
private const UInt32 WM_FONTCHANGE         = 0x001D;
private const UInt32 WM_GETDLGCODE         = 0x0087;
private const UInt32 WM_GETFONT        = 0x0031;
private const UInt32 WM_GETHOTKEY          = 0x0033;
private const UInt32 WM_GETICON        = 0x007F;
private const UInt32 WM_GETMINMAXINFO      = 0x0024;
private const UInt32 WM_GETOBJECT          = 0x003D;
private const UInt32 WM_GETTEXT        = 0x000D;
private const UInt32 WM_GETTEXTLENGTH      = 0x000E;
private const UInt32 WM_HANDHELDFIRST      = 0x0358;
private const UInt32 WM_HANDHELDLAST       = 0x035F;
private const UInt32 WM_HELP           = 0x0053;
private const UInt32 WM_HOTKEY         = 0x0312;
private const UInt32 WM_HSCROLL        = 0x0114;
private const UInt32 WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD       = 0x030E;
private const UInt32 WM_ICONERASEBKGND     = 0x0027;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_CHAR           = 0x0286;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_COMPOSITION    = 0x010F;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_COMPOSITIONFULL    = 0x0284;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_CONTROL        = 0x0283;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION     = 0x010E;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_KEYDOWN        = 0x0290;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_KEYLAST        = 0x010F;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_KEYUP          = 0x0291;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_NOTIFY         = 0x0282;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_REQUEST        = 0x0288;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_SELECT         = 0x0285;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_SETCONTEXT     = 0x0281;
private const UInt32 WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION   = 0x010D;
private const UInt32 WM_INITDIALOG         = 0x0110;
private const UInt32 WM_INITMENU           = 0x0116;
private const UInt32 WM_INITMENUPOPUP      = 0x0117;
private const UInt32 WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE    = 0x0051;
private const UInt32 WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x0050;
private const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN        = 0x0100;
private const UInt32 WM_KEYFIRST           = 0x0100;
private const UInt32 WM_KEYLAST        = 0x0108;
private const UInt32 WM_KEYUP          = 0x0101;
private const UInt32 WM_KILLFOCUS          = 0x0008;
private const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK      = 0x0203;
private const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN        = 0x0201;
private const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONUP          = 0x0202;
private const UInt32 WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK      = 0x0209;
private const UInt32 WM_MBUTTONDOWN        = 0x0207;
private const UInt32 WM_MBUTTONUP          = 0x0208;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIACTIVATE        = 0x0222;
private const UInt32 WM_MDICASCADE         = 0x0227;
private const UInt32 WM_MDICREATE          = 0x0220;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIDESTROY         = 0x0221;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIGETACTIVE       = 0x0229;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIICONARRANGE     = 0x0228;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIMAXIMIZE        = 0x0225;
private const UInt32 WM_MDINEXT        = 0x0224;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIREFRESHMENU     = 0x0234;
private const UInt32 WM_MDIRESTORE         = 0x0223;
private const UInt32 WM_MDISETMENU         = 0x0230;
private const UInt32 WM_MDITILE        = 0x0226;
private const UInt32 WM_MEASUREITEM        = 0x002C;
private const UInt32 WM_MENUCHAR           = 0x0120;
private const UInt32 WM_MENUCOMMAND        = 0x0126;
private const UInt32 WM_MENUDRAG           = 0x0123;
private const UInt32 WM_MENUGETOBJECT      = 0x0124;
private const UInt32 WM_MENURBUTTONUP      = 0x0122;
private const UInt32 WM_MENUSELECT         = 0x011F;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEACTIVATE      = 0x0021;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEFIRST         = 0x0200;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEHOVER         = 0x02A1;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSELAST          = 0x020D;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSELEAVE         = 0x02A3;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEMOVE          = 0x0200;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEWHEEL         = 0x020A;
private const UInt32 WM_MOUSEHWHEEL        = 0x020E;
private const UInt32 WM_MOVE           = 0x0003;
private const UInt32 WM_MOVING         = 0x0216;
private const UInt32 WM_NCACTIVATE         = 0x0086;
private const UInt32 WM_NCCALCSIZE         = 0x0083;
private const UInt32 WM_NCCREATE           = 0x0081;
private const UInt32 WM_NCDESTROY          = 0x0082;
private const UInt32 WM_NCHITTEST          = 0x0084;
private const UInt32 WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK    = 0x00A3;
private const UInt32 WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN      = 0x00A1;
private const UInt32 WM_NCLBUTTONUP        = 0x00A2;
private const UInt32 WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK    = 0x00A9;
private const UInt32 WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN      = 0x00A7;
private const UInt32 WM_NCMBUTTONUP        = 0x00A8;
private const UInt32 WM_NCMOUSEMOVE        = 0x00A0;
private const UInt32 WM_NCPAINT        = 0x0085;
private const UInt32 WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK    = 0x00A6;
private const UInt32 WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN      = 0x00A4;
private const UInt32 WM_NCRBUTTONUP        = 0x00A5;
private const UInt32 WM_NEXTDLGCTL         = 0x0028;
private const UInt32 WM_NEXTMENU           = 0x0213;
private const UInt32 WM_NOTIFY         = 0x004E;
private const UInt32 WM_NOTIFYFORMAT       = 0x0055;
private const UInt32 WM_NULL           = 0x0000;
private const UInt32 WM_PAINT          = 0x000F;
private const UInt32 WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD     = 0x0309;
private const UInt32 WM_PAINTICON          = 0x0026;
private const UInt32 WM_PALETTECHANGED     = 0x0311;
private const UInt32 WM_PALETTEISCHANGING      = 0x0310;
private const UInt32 WM_PARENTNOTIFY       = 0x0210;
private const UInt32 WM_PASTE          = 0x0302;
private const UInt32 WM_PENWINFIRST        = 0x0380;
private const UInt32 WM_PENWINLAST         = 0x038F;
private const UInt32 WM_POWER          = 0x0048;
private const UInt32 WM_POWERBROADCAST     = 0x0218;
private const UInt32 WM_PRINT          = 0x0317;
private const UInt32 WM_PRINTCLIENT        = 0x0318;
private const UInt32 WM_QUERYDRAGICON      = 0x0037;
private const UInt32 WM_QUERYENDSESSION    = 0x0011;
private const UInt32 WM_QUERYNEWPALETTE    = 0x030F;
private const UInt32 WM_QUERYOPEN          = 0x0013;
private const UInt32 WM_QUEUESYNC          = 0x0023;
private const UInt32 WM_QUIT           = 0x0012;
private const UInt32 WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK      = 0x0206;
private const UInt32 WM_RBUTTONDOWN        = 0x0204;
private const UInt32 WM_RBUTTONUP          = 0x0205;
private const UInt32 WM_RENDERALLFORMATS       = 0x0306;
private const UInt32 WM_RENDERFORMAT       = 0x0305;
private const UInt32 WM_SETCURSOR          = 0x0020;
private const UInt32 WM_SETFOCUS           = 0x0007;
private const UInt32 WM_SETFONT        = 0x0030;
private const UInt32 WM_SETHOTKEY          = 0x0032;
private const UInt32 WM_SETICON        = 0x0080;
private const UInt32 WM_SETREDRAW          = 0x000B;
private const UInt32 WM_SETTEXT        = 0x000C;
private const UInt32 WM_SETTINGCHANGE      = 0x001A;
private const UInt32 WM_SHOWWINDOW         = 0x0018;
private const UInt32 WM_SIZE           = 0x0005;
private const UInt32 WM_SIZECLIPBOARD      = 0x030B;
private const UInt32 WM_SIZING         = 0x0214;
private const UInt32 WM_SPOOLERSTATUS      = 0x002A;
private const UInt32 WM_STYLECHANGED       = 0x007D;
private const UInt32 WM_STYLECHANGING      = 0x007C;
private const UInt32 WM_SYNCPAINT          = 0x0088;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSCHAR        = 0x0106;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE     = 0x0015;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSCOMMAND         = 0x0112;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSDEADCHAR        = 0x0107;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSKEYDOWN         = 0x0104;
private const UInt32 WM_SYSKEYUP           = 0x0105;
private const UInt32 WM_TCARD          = 0x0052;
private const UInt32 WM_TIMECHANGE         = 0x001E;
private const UInt32 WM_TIMER          = 0x0113;
private const UInt32 WM_UNDO           = 0x0304;
private const UInt32 WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP    = 0x0125;
private const UInt32 WM_USER           = 0x0400;
private const UInt32 WM_USERCHANGED        = 0x0054;
private const UInt32 WM_VKEYTOITEM         = 0x002E;
private const UInt32 WM_VSCROLL        = 0x0115;
private const UInt32 WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD       = 0x030A;
private const UInt32 WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED       = 0x0047;
private const UInt32 WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING      = 0x0046;
private const UInt32 WM_WININICHANGE       = 0x001A;
private const UInt32 WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK      = 0x020D;
private const UInt32 WM_XBUTTONDOWN        = 0x020B;
private const UInt32 WM_XBUTTONUP          = 0x020C;
```